# How to get the chapter letter (not the number)

Tags: numbering, memoir

I use the `memoir` class, which [defines](https://texdoc.org/serve/memman.pdf/0) `appendix` (§6.2.1) as

> The \appendix declaration changes the numbering of chapters to an alphabetic form and also changes the names of chapters from \chaptername (default Chapter) to the value of \appendixname (default Appendix). Thus, the first and any subsequent \chapters after the \appendix command will be ‘Appendix A . . . ’, ‘Appendix B . . . ’, and so on

---

MWE :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,draft]{memoir}
\renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}

\usepackage{tabularray}
\begin{document}
    
    \appendix
    
    \chapter{Example}
    
    \renewcommand\thetable{A.\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}.\arabic{table}}
    
    % \usepackage{tabularray}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \refstepcounter{table}
        \label{tab:to-grab}
        \begin{tblr}{
            }
            A1 & B1 & C1 \\
            A2 & B2 & C2 \\
            A3 & B3 & C3 
        \end{tblr}
        \caption[]{Example}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

This gives me a caption of `Table A.1.0.2` which is what I want as output

My document is prone to changing at the phase it's in, and I would really like not to hard-code the `A` in there

Instead of A, I've tried

- `\arabic{part}` gives 0, which is correct, but this is not what I want
- `\arabic{appendix}` doesn't exist and fails with `Missing Number, treated as 0`

I would assume `\arabic` only gives a number. Is there a way to get the letter?

Comment: Why not just `\thechapter`?

Comment: @Mico That works great, feel free to post an answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want just the appendix "number" (in Alphabetic format) as a prefix, use

```
\thechapter
```

If you want both the appendix and section numbers as prefixes, use

```
\thesection
```

E.g., `\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection.\arabic{table}}`.